# syntax error with else

Tags: java

whenever I try to use the else statement I keep getting the error:   Syntax error on token "else", delete this token. This is annoying because I have tried copying it in exactly as I see it on about 5 different examples. And I still have not been able to write a line with the else condition without errors. I figure it must be something from a larger perspective that I am doing wrong, because I cannot write it successfully anywhere!! Below is the actual code that I am compiling and want to use it for.

```
 System.out.println("Enter start time");
 String startTime = console.nextLine();
 String [] tokens = startTime.split(":");
 double starttimeHours = Double.parseDouble(tokens[0]);
 double starttimeMinutes = Double.parseDouble(tokens[1]);{
   if (starttimeHours >=6 && starttimeHours <=9 );{
   int peaktimeWage = 4;}
   else
```

Thanks guys the if else statement works now. I have changed my code to this:

```
 System.out.println("Enter start time");
 String startTime = console.nextLine();
 String [] tokens = startTime.split(":");
 double starttimeHours = Double.parseDouble(tokens[0]);
 double starttimeMinutes = Double.parseDouble(tokens[1]);{
  if (starttimeHours >=6 && starttimeHours <=9 ){
  int peaktimeWages = 4;}
  else if  (starttimeHours >=1 && starttimeHours <=5 ){
  int peaktimeWages = 2;}

  else {int peaktimeWages = 3;}{
  System.out.println(peaktimeWages);

  }}}}
```

Now the issue I am having is at the last line of code:
        System.out.println(peaktimeWages);

It keeps saying peaktimeWages cannot be resolved to a variable, but I am not trying to resolve it to a variable, I am just trying to print it out. So the message seems wrong to me. Also I have previous code printed in the same manner as 
       System.out.println(peaktimeWages);

With only the variable different, so I do not know why it will not accept it. I think the problem must be from a previous section of code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to resolve "Syntax error on token "else"" in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17833861/how-to-resolve-syntax-error-on-token-else-in-java)

Answer (score 4):

You have an errant semicolon at the end of your `if` statement:

```
if (starttimeHours >=6 && starttimeHours <=9 );{// <-semicolon before the brace
```

This is prematurely closing your `if` statement, and the following block, and also the `else` isn't associated with the `if` statement as you intend them to be. Since an `else` statement must have a corresponding `if` statement, the compiler is complaining with an error.

Comment: It would appear you answered first ;) All the same answer though. +1

Answer (score 1):

Remove the semi-colon right after `if` `)`

```
 if (starttimeHours >=6 && starttimeHours <=9 ){
   int peaktimeWage = 4;}
   else
```

Having semi-colon terminates the if block, then else will be invalid syntax.

Comment: Thank you I finally wrote a conditional statement without as error! I feel better.

Answer (score 0):

You have a semicolon after the closing bracket of the if:

```
if (starttimeHours >=6 && starttimeHours <=9 );
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may have prematurely ended your `if` statement. Try deleting the `;` from this line:

```
if (starttimeHours >=6 && starttimeHours <=9 );{
```

Answer (score 0):

All of the other answers here, plus you also have an opening brace after `double starttimeMinutes = Double.parseDouble(tokens[1]);{` which comes before the `if` clause, so I think I win... :)

Comment: ok thanks Pedantic, the brace is still before the if clause just on the line above it, does it need to be on the line below right before the if?