# How to resolve "Syntax error on token "else"" in Java?

Tags: java, if-statement

I am new around here but let's get straight to the question:
When I was writing the following code for a class project calculator I came across a "token error". This is the full error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
Syntax error on token "else", delete this token

at calculatorApplet.main(calculatorApplet.java:42)
```

I wrote this code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class calculatorApplet
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Welcome to the Calculator!");
        String option = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Which calculator mode do you want?");
        if (option.equals("Addition"))
        {
            Double add1 = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Okay type the first number(s) of your addition problem."));
            Double add2 = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Now type the second number(s) of your addition problem."));
            Double preAdd = add1+add2;
            Double Add = preAdd;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The sum is " + Add + ".");
        }
        else
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Huh?");
        }
        if (option.equals("Subtraction"))
        {
            Double sub1 = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Okay type the first number(s) of your subtraction problem."));
            Double sub2 = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Now type the second number(s) of your subtraction problem."));
            Double preSub = sub1-sub2;
            Double Sub = preSub;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The difference is " + Sub + ".");
        }
        else
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Huh?");
        }
        if (option.equals("Multiplication"));
        {
            Double mult1 = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Okay type the first number(s) of your multiplication problem."));
            Double mult2 = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Now type the second number(s) of your multiplication problem."));
            Double preMult = mult1*mult2;
            Double Mult = preMult;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The product is " + Mult + ".");
        }
        else //Here is the error.
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Huh?");
        } //Here ends the error.
        if (option.equals("Division"))
        {
            Double div1 = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Okay type the first number(s) of your division problem."));
            Double div2 = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Now type the second number(s) of your division problem."));
            Double preDiv = div1/div2;
            Double Div = preDiv;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The quotient is " + Div + ".");
        }
        else
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Huh?");
        }
        //End of if statements.
    } 

}
```

That's the code and I commented the area where the token error is. Maybe the solution is right in my face. I want my code to be a calculator so if you guys can fix my code to not conflict with the math operations. Thanks and I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem is the semicolon after the `if`.

The grammar is `if` `(` *condition* `)` *expression-or-block* { `else` *expression-or-block* }

Since `;` is an empty expression, this works for an if clause and nothing happens in the then clause - in your case syntactically there is no else clause, since your if statement statements ends with the semicolon and is followed by a simple block. Then the tokenizer detects a dangling `else` token and complains.

Answer (score 19):

Remove the `;` from the line end here:

`if (option.equals("Multiplication"));`

Answer (score 7):

You have a semi-colon at the end of the If statement preceding where the error is occuring.

```
if (option.equals("Multiplication"));
```

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
if (option.equals("Multiplication"));
```

to

```
if (option.equals("Multiplication"))
```

without the semicolon

Answer (score 1):

remove semicolon ( ;) at the end of the statement `if (option.equals("Multiplication"));`

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
if (option.equals("Multiplication"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Need no ; at the end of if condition

if(option.equals("Multiplication"))

Answer (score -1):

remove the semicolon from the if statement

```
if (option.equals("Multiplication"));
```

should be

```
if (option.equals("Multiplication"))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! When answering questions, please take the time to read the previously provided answers. In this instance, there are multiple we received answers already giving the answer. Ask yourself, "Is my answer adding to the community?"