# Why my code for prefixAgain is not working?

Tags: java, string

Given a string, consider the prefix string made of the first N chars of the string. Does that prefix string appear somewhere else in the string? Assume that the string is not empty and that N is in the range 1..str.length().

```
public boolean prefixAgain(String str, int n) {
    String res = "";
    String res1 = "";
    String s = str.substring(0,n);
    for ( int i = 0  ; i < n ; i++ ) { 
        res += str.charAt(i) ;  
        if (s.equalsIgnoreCase(res)); {
            return true;  
        } else { 
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you had formatting your code properly this would be easier to see, but you have an extra semicolon after your `if` statement that shouldn't be there.  **Edit:** Much better.  Now it should be easier to spot.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When asking about code that isn’t working, it’s great that you’re so clear about the expected behaviour. We also need to know precisely *how* it isn’t working: Are you getting wrong results? If so, give an example. Are you seeing any error message? If so, quote verbatim in the question. Error messages can tell us a whole lot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve “Syntax error on token ”else“” in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17833861/how-to-resolve-syntax-error-on-token-else-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

There are many problems with your solution:

- Why do you need to loop only till `n` in the `prefixAgain` method? You probably need to go till `str.length()`
- Your `res` variable will again be a prefix of the string and will be of no use.
- Why are you having `;` after the `if`?
- Using `+=` on Strings in a loop can be very expensive. You should always consider using `StringBuilder` and it's `append` method.

The following method does what you want:

```java
public boolean prefixAgain(String str, int n) {
    if (str.length() == 1) return false;
    String s = str.substring(0, n);
    return str.substring(1).contains(s);
}
```

**The main idea is to just search the required prefix in the substring starting from 2nd character (the character at index `1`).**

Keep it simple. :)